# What is the difference between testing on Safari vs Webkit?

Tags: safari, cross-browser, webkit, playwright

I'm looking at writing some E2E tests using Playwright. I can see that the library allows tests to be run against Chromium, Firefox and Webkit. My understanding is that Webkit is the underlying engine of Safari, and Chromium is the base of Chrome (and other browsers).

When it comes to testing against Webkit/Chromium, how close is it to testing against the user facing browsers which use the underlying engines? I'd imagine that there would be some quirks which the user can run in to whilst using Safari and it wouldn't be caught when running the tests on Webkit.

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Stock browsers like Google Chrome, Apple Safari embed rendering engines (Chromium, WebKit) and add stuff on top of them. In particular, they add proprietary media codecs, inject browser extensions, etc. They also add surrounding interfaces such as bookmarks sync. But they reuse the underlying web platform implementation.

#### Chromium

Chromium is the open source web platform implementation used by Google Chrome, Opera, Microsoft Edge and other browsers. It implements web specs, renders content, works with network, etc. Playwright uses a stock Chromium build that can be automated with the Playwright API for e2e testing.

For Google Chrome things are simple: Chromium is a safe target to test, modulo proprietary media codecs and DRM. You can point Playwright against stock Chrome Canary or Edge Canary to use proprietary media codecs.

#### WebKit

WebKit is the open source web platform implementation used by Apple Safari and Epiphany. As of June 2020, Playwright provides a WebKit build that can be automated with the Playwright API for e2e testing. Playwright WebKit works across all platforms (macOS, Linux, Windows), in both headless and headful modes.

When WebKit runs on macOS, it is a safe target to test Safari. WebKit on Linux and Windows differs from Apple Safari in the following ways: it uses a non-macOS network stack, uses non-Core Animation to composite scene and produce image raster. This means that screenshots on Linux and Windows will not perfectly match screenshots from macOS. In terms of the web platform, the same WebKit code will layout the page and run JavaScript—it will match how WebKit works in Safari.

To conclude, we consider the browsers provided by Playwright to be the best of what you can get for e2e testing. Running WebKit on a Linux CI would use a different compositing pipeline than macOS, but it can be used for e2e testing of web applications in WebKit-powered browsers.

Comment: This is anecdotal, but I'm running on macOS and I ran into a difference between Playwright's webkit and Safari: [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046548/a-link-that-receives-pointer-events-after-animating-isnt-clickable-in-safari) affects Safari but my tests don't fail in Playwright. It could be a Safari issue (not webkit), but it's definitely not great for Playwright: I don't feel confident that my UI tests are really covering Safari

Comment: @arjunattam, Is the correct interpretation of your second paragraph that if you are not visual testing running webkit tests on windows or linux will yield the same results as running them on macos?

Answer (score 2):

I've found there are some differences between webkit and Safari depending on which version of the two you're testing against.

I was testing Safari 16.0, and for my purposes Playwright 1v17 seemed to match very well. Upgrading to Safari 16.2 didn't seem to affect that.

But upgrading Playwright to 1v28 though seemed to change the behaviour around getting selection bounding boxes. It's seems more correct, but it's no longer consistent with Safari 16.2.

I'm assuming that WebKit is a bit ahead of Safari, and at some point Safari will catch up, and we'll see they are behaving the same again, but so far that's not happened. (Or maybe it has already, I'm a couple of versions behind at this point).

My solution has been to use both the latest version of Playwright for testing Chromium and Firefox, but use the older version for testing Safari. I am also testing webkit from Playwright 1v28 for interest right now, but I expect Safari will start showing that behaviour at some point.

(NB: Getting the bounding boxes of selections gets different results from each browser, so it's not too surprising that it's changing in WebKit right now. The change seems to be closer to Chrome's behaviour but still not the same).

In case it helps anyone, in my package.json devDependencies I have

```
"playwright1v17": "npm:playwright@~1.17.2",
"playwright1v28": "npm:playwright@~1.28.1",
```

and then in the test script I do

```
import { chromium, webkit, firefox } from 'playwright1v28';
import { webkit as safari16v1 } from 'playwright1v17';
```

That lets me test both versions of webkit and compare, as well as Chromium and Firefox.